# Server Error in '/' Application. on New MVC Project using VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I reinstalled VS2013 on my windows 10 machine.

I created a new MVC Project. Built it and viewed on the browser with no problems. I then created a **Customers** controller and everything seem ok until I tried to view it. 
When opened in the browser (*http://localhost:63953/Customers/Index*) I get **"Server Error in '/' Application.".**

[image]

Steps I tried. Removed temp files. Cleared cache. still not solving the issue.

Everything seem to have been created correctly but for some reason it doesn't know where it is.

[image]

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: `CustomersController` (not `Customers`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every controller name should end with the word "Controller" on ASP.NET MVC. So, Rename your Customer class to CustomerController.

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```